# The BOS FBX import / export addon for blender does not work

Tags: rigging, export, add-on, .fbx

I was looking for a **better FBX support** for Blender and I found this **FBX exporter**,which uses the official **Autodesk FBX SDK (2015)** :

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/12/17/Better-FBX-Support-in-Blender-Using-The-Autodesk-FBX-SDK.aspx

but it didn't work for me. It gives the same error that someone mentioned on the post,as you can see below :

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I used the **2015** version of the addon,included inside the file : **BL_20150704.zip** and the **2015** version of the **umconv Autodesk FBX SDK already compiled**,included inside the file : **umconv20150704.zip**

So,where is the error ? How did you fix this error ? thanks.

Comment: If you can, try and get ahold of a newer version. There's a possibility that the 2015 version doesn't integrate with the newer versions of Blender

Comment: I have installed new versions of the autodesk SDK,but on the blender FBX configuration menu I see only the 2015 version available....

Comment: https://www.deviantart.com/amyaimei/journal/Bos-FBX-Importer-Exporter-for-Blender-2-80-Win64-724179315